# Improve query performance from many Master table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-tuning

I have a query. I have created index for all joined key, pre-filter the master table and choose specific rows to select, but it still take long time to show(sometimes it hangs). What should We do to improve the performance?

```
SELECT *
FROM   t_responden a
       INNER JOIN t_kepemilikan_tik b
               ON a.res_id = b.res_id
       INNER JOIN t_televisi c
               ON a.res_id = c.res_id
       INNER JOIN t_telepon_hp d
               ON a.res_id = d.res_id
       INNER JOIN t_radio e
               ON a.res_id = e.res_id
       INNER JOIN t_media_cetak f
               ON a.res_id = f.res_id
       INNER JOIN t_internet g
               ON a.res_id = g.res_id
       LEFT JOIN t_mst_pendidikan n
              ON a.res_pendidikan_kk = n.kd_pendidikan
       LEFT JOIN t_mst_pendidikan o
              ON a.res_pendidikan = o.kd_pendidikan
       LEFT JOIN t_mst_penghasilan p
              ON a.res_penghasilan = p.kd_penghasilan

       LEFT JOIN t_mst_aksesibilitas q
              ON a.res_aksesibilitas = q.kd_akses
       LEFT JOIN t_mst_mobilitas r
              ON a.res_mobilitas = r.kd_mobilitas
       LEFT JOIN t_mst_pekerjaan s
              ON a.res_pekerjaan = s.kode
       LEFT JOIN t_mst_pengeluaran t
              ON a.res_pengeluaran = t.kode

       INNER JOIN t_pernyataan h
               ON a.res_id = h.res_id

       INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM t_mst_prop WHERE kode IN ( '3200', '1600', '1800', '3600' )) i
               ON a.res_propinsi = i.kode

       INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM t_mst_kabkota WHERE kode_prop IN ( '3200', '1600', '1800', '3600' )) j
               ON ( a.res_kabkota = j.kode
                    AND a.res_propinsi = j.kode_prop )

       INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM t_mst_kec WHERE kode_prop IN ( '3200', '1600', '1800', '3600' )) k
               ON ( a.res_kecamatan = k.kode
                    AND a.res_kabkota = k.kode_kabkota
                    AND a.res_propinsi = k.kode_prop )

       INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM t_mst_desa WHERE kode_prop IN ( '3200', '1600', '1800', '3600' ))l
               ON ( a.res_keldesa = l.kode
                    AND a.res_kabkota = l.kode_kabkota
                    AND a.res_propinsi = l.kode_prop
                    AND l.kode_kec = a.res_kecamatan )

WHERE  a.res_tahunsurvei = 2013
       AND res_propinsi IN ( '3200', '1600', '1800', '3600' )
ORDER  BY 1
```

Comment: what the EXPLAIN says about this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      *
   FROM   
      t_responden a
         INNER JOIN t_kepemilikan_tik b
            ON a.res_id = b.res_id
         INNER JOIN t_televisi c
            ON a.res_id = c.res_id
         INNER JOIN t_telepon_hp d
            ON a.res_id = d.res_id
         INNER JOIN t_radio e
            ON a.res_id = e.res_id
         INNER JOIN t_media_cetak f
            ON a.res_id = f.res_id
         INNER JOIN t_internet g
            ON a.res_id = g.res_id
         LEFT JOIN t_mst_pendidikan n
            ON a.res_pendidikan_kk = n.kd_pendidikan
         LEFT JOIN t_mst_pendidikan o
            ON a.res_pendidikan = o.kd_pendidikan
         LEFT JOIN t_mst_penghasilan p
            ON a.res_penghasilan = p.kd_penghasilan
         LEFT JOIN t_mst_aksesibilitas q
            ON a.res_aksesibilitas = q.kd_akses
         LEFT JOIN t_mst_mobilitas r
            ON a.res_mobilitas = r.kd_mobilitas
         LEFT JOIN t_mst_pekerjaan s
            ON a.res_pekerjaan = s.kode
         LEFT JOIN t_mst_pengeluaran t
            ON a.res_pengeluaran = t.kode
         INNER JOIN t_pernyataan h
            ON a.res_id = h.res_id

         INNER JOIN t_mst_prop i
            ON a.res_propinsi = i.kode
         INNER JOIN t_mst_kabkota j
               ON  a.res_propinsi = j.kode_prop 
               AND a.res_kabkota = j.kode
         INNER JOIN t_mst_kec k
               ON a.res_propinsi = k.kode_prop
               AND a.res_kecamatan = k.kode
               AND a.res_kabkota = k.kode_kabkota
         INNER JOIN t_mst_desa l
               ON  a.res_propinsi = l.kode_prop
               AND a.res_keldesa = l.kode
               AND a.res_kabkota = l.kode_kabkota
               AND a.res_kecamatan = l.kode_kec
   WHERE  
          a.res_tahunsurvei = 2013
      AND a.res_propinsi IN ( '3200', '1600', '1800', '3600' )
   ORDER BY 
      1
```

You should have an index on your t_responden table ON ( res_tahunsurvei, res_propinsi) to match your where qualification criteria.  Additionally, all your inner joins to the other tables where you are applying the IN via sub-selects is killing you.  You are already limiting on the "kode"s in the where, so if you apply that as your join you should be good.

Additionally, since all the other tables appear to be more "lookup", I've added "STRAIGHT_JOIN" to tell MySQL to query in the order the tables you have listed

Comment: Awesome! does, the `STRAIGHT_JOIN` affect result?

Comment: @WildanMuhlis, what was vs what IS the new performance first, then I can clarify for you.

Comment: The Query took only `0.0188` sec

Comment: @WildanMuhlis, sometimes when you have a main table with many secondary lookups, the sql engine might try to think for you by looking at a smaller table result and use that as a basis to backfill join the others.  Since you are working with a known "primary" table of all big records in question and the others are off-shoot lookup references, STRAIGHT_JOIN runs the query based on your first table first then joins to the rest and applies your query criteria... I guess the .0188 is good enough for you :)

Comment: but, if we call description column from master table why the description doesn't shown?

Comment: @WildanMuhlis, I can't specificially answer because you have SELECT * (all field) instead of select a.field1, a.field2, b.fieldX, c.fieldY...  If multiple tables have a same column name, it would suffix them like Description_a, Description_b, description_c and the _a, _b, _c don't necessarily correspond to the table the fields are coming from, just that they are duplicate column names and MySQL assigns them the suffix